# What is the right context to use the term "vis a vis"?

Tags: sens

To me it sounds the same as: 'à propos de..' or 'par rapport à..' and 'au sujet de..' but I am not sure if it is a bit different.

Comment: Searching for it online I found this is a French word/expression used also in English conveying kinda the same meaning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'vis-à-vis' is more about two things, the meaning is very similar to 'par rapport' but is more used for confrontation between two things:

> "Quant à la question de la dépréciation de l'euro vis-à-vis du dollar, soulevée par l'autre partie intéressée, il est admis [...] "
>
> "With regard to the issue of the depreciation of the euro against the dollar raised by the other interested party, it was [...]"

Here 'vis-à-vis' confronts the Euro and the Dollar but 'Par rapport' could have been used too.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tim's answer I would like to say that `vis-à-vis` could also be used in housing context.

> un appartement sans vis-à-vis

means an apartment with no other apartment in front of it

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers, it's important to note that when followed by a noun, it's *vis-à-vis **de*** in French, whereas in English it's just "vis-à-vis" (or "vis-a-vis").

> Quelle est notre position vis-à-vis de ces développements ?
>
> What is our position vis-a-vis these developments?